# How to format date from 12h to 24h in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to format a 12h date to 24h date, but is not working, maybe I am doing something wrong. I'll share the code below so maybe you can help me.

"syncViewModel._order.deliveryDate" is the date that I am getting from the backend and is a string.

```
 Text(dateFormatTime(date: syncViewModel._order.deliveryDate ?? ""), style: .time)
```

```
  func dateFormatTime(date : String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB") as Locale
        return dateFormatter.date(from: date) ?? Date.now
    }
```

This is the format of my date : 2022-01-25T17:00:00
[image]

Comment: This is too vague. What is the dateFormat of your order deliveryDate?

Comment: @LeoDabus The date format is iso8601

Comment: Still too vague. There is many variations.

Comment: @LeoDabus I added a picture. So, the date is working right, but instead of showing "5:00 PM", i want "17:00", 24h format. Also added the date that came from my backend. Check edit

Comment: Are you sure that the date timezone is the current timezone? iso8601 timezone usually is UTC

Comment: Instead of using that init for Text you can use one that takes a FormatStyle and supply your wanted format

Comment: I think everything is just fine. Your func converts the iso8601 string into a specific point in time – just be careful which timezone the string relates to. And it is about timezone, not locale!!! The way this time is presented using .style depends on the settings of the device its running on. If you set the region of your Simulator e.g. to Italy, it displays "17:00"

Answer (score 1):

You use a date formatter to convert a date string to a `Date`. You can then use an additional date formatter, to directly return the time in the format that you want, as a string:

```
func timeIn24HourFormat(from date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

That way you can use it in SwiftUI directly, without requesting the `time` style:

```
Text(timeIn24HourFormat(from: dateFormatTime(date: "2021-07-14T17:00:00")))
```

Comment: This works a treat, thank you.  I'll be able to use this to edit it with a conditional for 12 and 24 hour formats in a setting in my app for how the user wants their time to be displayed.   Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jorge's answer, I edited the code to be able to accept a Bool to change between 12 and 24 hour format so the user can choose.

```
struct DateFormat {
   // Change time from 12 hour to 24 hour format
   static func timeHourFormat(from date: Date, twentyFourHourFormat: Bool) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = twentyFourHourFormat ? "HH:mm" : "hh:mm"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
   }
}
```

Then to apply the change (in SwiftUI) you can save the state first with:

```
@AppStorage("twentyFourHourFormat") var twentyFourHourFormat = true
```

And call the function with

```
Text(DateFormat.timeHourFormat(from: myDateTime ?? Date.now, twentyFourHourFormat: twentyFourHourFormat))
```

Just choose a toggle button or some or conditional setter to change between *true* and *false*.
*myDateTime* is taken from a Core Data return, hence the optional binding within the function call, but you can omit this and the *??* just use Date.now.